# json data storage with versioning

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson, nosql

### Problem definition:

There is a Java server which stores `JSON` data that can be mapped to a Java Class. The Java Class is subject to changes. The goal is to be able to update the Java Class and still be able to decode the `JSON` data of an older version to a Java Object of a newer version. There should be a good versioning system in place. For example the ability to add a new field to the Java Class with a default value. In the case the old `JSON` data doesn't have this field, the Java object can use the default value of the field.

### Questions:

- *I've seen `GSON`, but [the versioning support](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Versioning-Support) is too limited.*

Did I miss something? Are there other libraries that have a better versioning support?

- *How should one store that `JSON` data?*

I see two options. Option 1: I can store those `JSON` files (which have a common structure if they have the same version) separately in a folder. For example I have 2 files: json/j1.json and json/j2.json. Option 2: I can use a `NoSQL` Database such as `MongoDB`. But Does this have an advantage over the previous option? It is pointless to ask for a `BasicDBObject` in a `DBCollection` since I need it to be able to cast it to another Java Class. Which option is recommended for this case? Maybe another option is better suited?

Comment: For point 1, this might help (although it looks like bad news for you)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425881/upgrade-path-for-json-file-format

Comment: Google's Protocol Buffer looks interesting, but doesn't have a proper implementation with Java annotations.

Comment: Not that it helps your use of Java, but interestingly, the C# driver happens to support your pattern (as you can ignore missing fields and have defaults for non-existent fields).

Comment: yes all .net languages do :(

Comment: The most clean solution I found so far: use the build-in MappingMongoConverter of spring-data-mongodb. 1) Adding fields: you can add fields to the stored BSON. To convert this new BSON to a POJO, the new field will be skipped for the old version of the POJO. When deploying the new version of the POJO, add a constructor param that reads the new field. When a user makes a request to read such a  POJO, first the version of the stored BSON is checked. If the versions don't match, the field is added to the BSON. In the background a BATCH procress runs that updates all other old BSONs in advance.

Comment: 2) removing fields: this happens in steps. First step is to update the POJO that doesn't use the field anymore and deploy this new version v1.2. When no users use the old version v1.1, you can deploy a new version v1.3 that removes that field. 3) modify the name of a member field of the POJO: Combination of 1 and 2. Add an extra field with the new name and keep the old one. When no users use the old version, you can deploy a new version that removes the old field name.

Comment: The advantage of using MongoDB over simple JSON files is that, like any database, you can query your documents.  So if you think any kind of search will be useful, MongoDB might be an attractive option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Jackson support at the time of writing this (2.9.x), however, the [Jackson Model Versioning Module](https://github.com/jonpeterson/jackson-module-model-versioning) adds versioning support which can be used to convert old versions of JSON models to the current version (and vice-versa) before being mapped to the POJO.

See my answer on [Jackson 2 support for versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083992/1073826) for an example of how GSON's basic versioning functionality can be mapped to this module. See the [module's GitHub page](https://github.com/jonpeterson/jackson-module-model-versioning) for examples of the full functionality.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this module. I have also written a [Spring MVC ResponseBodyAdvise](https://github.com/jonpeterson/spring-webmvc-model-versioning) for using the module.

Answer (score 0):

The document store `BaseX` has `JSON` modules and certainly, through `FLOWR` those are easily enough added to a database.  Quite easily, and well documented.

```
  let $content := file:read-text('x.json')
  let $json := json:parse($content)
  return admin:write-log($json)
```

something like that, not sure of your requirements, but that can certainly get fed into a database.